# Problems compiling example scalapack application

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, lapack, blas, scalapack

When I do:

```
mpif77 example1.f -L scalapack/scalapack-1.8.0/ -lscalapack -L scalapack/blacs/BLACS/LIB -l:blacsF77init_MPI-LINUX-0.a -l:blacs_MPI-LINUX-0.a -l:blacsF77init_MPI-LINUX-0.a -L scalapack/blas/BLAS/ -l:blas_LINUX.a  -L scalapack/lapack/ -llapack -L/cm/shared/apps/gcc/4.4.6/lib64/ -lgfortran
```

I get:

```
scalapack//blas_LINUX.a(xerbla.o): In function `xerbla_':
xerbla.f:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
xerbla.f:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could it be something with the order in which the libraries are linked?

[How to Run Example Program Using MPI](http://netlib.org/scalapack/slug/node26.html#SECTION04210000000000000000)

Answer (score 1):

It linking error. These dependences usually come when using different fortran compilers for libraries and executables (f77, f90). Try to use `mpif90` to compile your example.

You can test using :

```
$ mpif77 --showme
gfortran -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -pthread -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lmpi_f77 -lmpi -ldl -lhwloc
$ mpif90 --showme
gfortran -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -pthread -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lmpi_f90 -lmpi_f77 -lmpi -ldl -lhwloc
```

The only difference is `-lmpi_f90`